# How do I get the generated key for an item add to Firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onclicklistener

Trying to get the generated key for item added, when using the `onItemClickListener`,

[image]

Please see my code, :

```
ref = new Firebase("https://.......firebaseio.com/Service");
        final FirebaseListAdapter<MainCategory> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<MainCategory>(getActivity(), MainCategory.class,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                ref) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View view, MainCategory s, int i) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setText(s.getTitle());

            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String itemId = String.valueOf(parent.getId());
                String root = String.valueOf(ref.getRoot().getKey());
                MainCategory object = (MainCategory) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


                Toast.makeText(getContext(), itemId+"____"+"__"+root, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String key = adapter.getRef(position).getKey()
}
```